# call a method in activity when certain data recived

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to build an app that call a method in `activity` when a certain data is received from server, I use `socket` for my conection to server and when a certain message recived it calls `Task3` which I want to call a method in activity, this is a part of my code for data ,which is a shared code to use in `ios` and `android` what should I do ?

```
public string Task3(ClientClass NCC)
{
    string servermessage = ByteToString(NCC.NetMessageResived); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by using `BroadcastReceivers`. In your class that received the message from the server you can raise an intent like

```
String serverResponse = ...;
String action = "MESSAGE_RECEIVED_FROM_SERVER";
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(action);
intent.putExtra("msg", serverResponse );

context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And now in your activity you need to create an `Broadcast Receiver` that will register for the `MESSAGE_RECEIVED_FROM_SERVER`intent. And when receiving the intent you can call the desired method from the activity.

You can use an example from [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm) or [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your scenario u can adopt given below methods

- Try using an **interface**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16443645/4247543

- if the above method is not helping then try using **EventBus**

please follow below link to know more of Event Bus

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

http://gunhansancar.com/ease-communication-between-activities-fragments-services/

- **BroadcastReceiver**  as mentioned could also help for enabling communication.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10084754/4247543

- You can use **observers**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30964385/4247543

Hopes it helps.

Comment: im trying to write this code in order to share in both ios and android , which of following methods is available in both of them ?

Comment: not sure ios .... but i saw SwiftEventBus.. https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus